# Adding to (or overriding) a core class method in cakePHP

Tags: php, datasource, cakephp-2.7

We are using cakePHP 2.7.x.

The question I have is with overriding a core class -- or specifically adding functionality to a method without modifying the core code.

I need to add some functionality to the method:
`cake/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource->BuildColumn()`

The docs say to put the whole class in the same location under app, and then the App loader will load it. So I copied the class to
`marketplace/Model/Datasource/DboSource`
and added my code snippet. Unfortunately nothing has changed.

If I add my change directly to the original method, everything works fine.

*Context:*
Inside that method all default values are quoted indiscriminately. Therefore something like `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is interpreted and run as `DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` which obviously doesn't work as intended.
Specifically it is giving me the error `"Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'created'"` when trying to cake bake a fixture.

I was directed to the cause of the problem, and a suggested fix for cakePHP 1.2.6, here:
http://mamchenkov.net/wordpress/2010/04/21/unit-tests-with-cakephp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#overriding-classes-in-cakephp):

> You can override almost every class in the framework, exceptions are
>   the App and Configure classes. Whenever you like to perform such
>   overriding, just add your class to your app/Lib folder mimicking the
>   internal structure of the framework

So the path should be `marketplace/Lib/Model/Datasource/DboSource`, not `marketplace/Model/Datasource/DboSource`

Comment: Thanks for the input.
I have changed the path, however the results are still the same.
Do I need to modify the new DboSource file at all?

Comment: I just checked this, copied the DboSource from the `lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php` into `app/Lib/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php`, included a simple `die("test")` by the beggining of the file, and it was called. Are you sure your file structure is correct?

Comment: Very odd indeed. I have just tried the same thing, adding `die("test");` in the first line of the constructor. It wasn't called at all.

I suspect then that something is wrong/different with our specific instance of cake.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there was something up with my vagrant machine. After I restarted that, doing just as Bruno Ferriera outlined works perfectly!